Installing Ubuntu in WSL failed with Error code: Wsl/Service/RegisterDistro/CreateVm/ConfigureNetworking/HNS/0x8007001f
Windows Version
Microsoft Windows [Version: 10.0.22621.3374]
WSL Version
2.1.5.0
Are you using WSL 1 or WSL 2?

[X] WSL 2
[ ] WSL 1

Kernel Version
5.15.146.1-2
Distro Version
None(Cannot install)
Other Software
Docker Desktop Windows, Docker version 25.0.3, build 4debf41
Repro Steps

Download Docker Desktop Windows at first, run the Docker Desktop Installer.exe to install Docker Desktop 4.28.0(139021)

After installed, I should complete the installation of Docker Desktop by ticking the choice using recommended settings(requires administrator password). Surely I did and there was a prompt reading : "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.admin.exe" wsl -update(I did not install WSL before).

It seems that the command did not work because after the setting up of Docker including agreeing with the wsl -update, I ran wsl --version in the Powershell, succeeded to see the installation of WSL but without any distribution installed as expected. See：

Windows PowerShell

版权所有(C) Microsoft Corporation。保留所有权利。
安装最新的 PowerShe11,了解新功能和改进!https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C: \WINDOWS\system32> ws1 -- version
WSL 版本:2.1.5.0
内核版本:5.15.146.1-2
WSLg 版本:1.0.60
MSRDC 版本:1.2.5105
Direct3D 版本:1.611.1-81528511
DXCore 版本:10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700. rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows 版本:10.0.22621.3374
PS C: \WINDOWS\system32> wsl -1 -v
适用于 Linux 的 Windows 子系统没有安装的分发版。

使用’wsl.exe -- list -- online'列出可用的分发版
和'ws1. exe -- install<Distro>'进行安装。

也可以通过访问 Microsoft Store 来安装分发版:
https://aka. ms/wslstore
Error code: Wsl/WSL_E_DEFAULT_DISTRO_NOT_FOUND
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>



Then ran Docker Desktop and there would be an Unexpected WSL error as follows：


Docker Desktop
Docker Desktop - Unexpected WSL error
An unexpected error was encountered while executing a WSL command.
Common causes include access rights issues, which occur after waking
the computer or not being connected to your domain/active directory.
Please try shutting WSL down (wsl -- shutdown) and/or rebooting your
computer. If not sufficient, WSL may need to be reinstalled fully. As
a last resort, try to uninstall/reinstall Docker Desktop. If the issue
persists please collect diagnostics and submit an issue ...:
//docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/#diagnose-from-the-termin
...
Diagnose & Feedback
X
X
Quit
Reset Docker to factory defaults


Diagnostics files obtained by running & "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.diagnose.exe" gather -upload in PowerShell is as follows
DockerDiagnosis.zip

Next I performed self-diagnose tool by running & "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.diagnose.exe" check in PowerShell.The screenshot is as follows

管理员:Windows PowerShell Please note the following 12 warnings:
1 : The check: is the application running? Produced the following
warning: Docker is not running
Is the Docker Desktop application running?
2 : The check: are WSL distros installed? Produced the following
warning: WSL Distribution docker-desktop is missing
The Docker engine uses several WSL distributions. Therefore these must
be installed.
3 : The check: are WSL distros installed? Produced the following
warning: WSL Distribution docker-desktop is missing
The Docker engine uses several WSL distributions. Therefore these must
be installed.
4 : The check: is the WSL 2 Linux filesystem corrupt? Produced the
following warning: prereq failed: are WSL distros installed?
If the WSL 2 Linux filesystem is corrupt then Docker Desktop cannot
start. There is a known issue fixed in Windows Insider builds which
can cause filesystem corruption, see: https://github.
com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5895
Try running "wsl -- shutdown" to stop your WSL Virtual Machine. When
it restarts it will run a filesystem check and hopefully fix the
problem.
5 : The check: are WSL distros installed? Produced the following
warning: WSL Distribution docker-desktop is missing


If the subnet used by a Docker network overlaps with an IP used by the
host, then containers won't be able to contact the overlapping IP
addresses.
Try configuring the IP address range used by networks: in your
docker-compose. yml. See https://docs. docker.
com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address
Please investigate the following 2 issues:
1 : The test: is the application running? Failed with: Docker is not
running
Is the Docker Desktop application running?
2 : The test: are WSL distros installed? Failed with: WSL Distribution
docker-desktop is missing
The Docker engine uses several WSL distributions. Therefore these must
be installed.
PS C: \Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources>


From now on I would infer that something wrong with the installing of my WSL distros.

Since WSL Distribution docker-desktop is missing , I tried whether other distros could be installed successfully. Unfortunately, one can observe that WSL was installed and updated successfully while no distros installed.

Then I ran wsl --install, the Ubuntu was installed by default but after only a while I encountered a fatal error with error code: 0x8007001f. See:
Ubuntu

PS C: \Program Files \Docker \Docker \resources> ws1 -1 -v 适用于 Linux 的
Windows 子系统没有安装的分发版。
使用’wsl. exe -- list -- online' 列出可用的分发版 和
也可以通过访问 Microsoft Store 来安装分发版: https://aka. ms/wslstore Error code:
Ws1/WSL_E_DEFAULT_DISTRO_NOT_FOUND PS C: \Program
Files\Docker\Docker\resources> ws1 -- install 正在安装:Ubuntu 已安装 Ubuntu。
正在启动 Ubuntu ... Installing, this may take a few minutes ...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8007001f Error:
0x8007001f ???????????????
Press any key to continue ...
wsl. exe -- install'进行安装。


From some tutorials, I check the support for Hardware Virtulization in BIOS, whether ticking the checkboxs for Virtual Machine Platform and Windows Subsystem for Linux in Windows features, however, failed again.
The tutorial link is as follows which would be helpful for most of the problems encountering WSL error:
Tutorial

Unable to install the distributions of Linux through Microsoft stores or PowerShell command line, I decided to download the Ubuntu WSL distribution rootfs and directly imort it into my WSL .

Follow the post at the website AskUbuntu, I downloaded ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz and tried to import it. We see:


选择 管理员:Windows PowerShell S C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources>#注意:如果路径中存在空格,请使用双引号”
wsl -- import Ubuntu-20. 04 "D: \WSL\Ubuntu-20. 04" "D: \WSL\Ubuntu\ubuntu-20. 04-server-cloudimg-amd64-ws1. rootfs. tar. gz
正在导入,这可能需要几分钟时间。 无法配置 networkingMode
Nat)(网络。若要禁用网络,请在C:\Users\拯救者青音.wslconfig中设置“ws12.networkingMode=None”
rror code:
Wsl/Service/RegisterDistro/CreateVm/ConfigureNetworking/HNS/0x8007001f
S C: \Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources> The same error code with
directly installing distros in the PowerShell through command line,
error code: 0x8007001f




Expected Behavior
Installing the distros successfully.
Actual Behavior
Error code: 0x8007001f
Diagnostic Logs
All screenshots, links and files are attached in the section of Repro Steps
